How to extract data from requests sent to sites on the network tab found in devtools?
I am using selenium on python for automations.
What i'm referring to is for example on this site https://app.opulabs.com/login entering an email and password then pressing "continue" A "login" request will be sent which can be found by going to devtools on the network tab. On the payload section of that request the entered credentials could be found. I want to extract this information in my automation. Is it possible to do this?

You might need to use "seleniumwire" instead of just selenium.
It is designed to intercept and modify browser requests during a Selenium session. It also lets you capture network traffic, including request payloads and headers.
